# Batch Job causing an error in FSC

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch, asynchronous, financial-services-cloud

I wrote a visualforce page that launches a batch job that processes records in batches, the batch creates households, person accounts, and then financial accounts for Salesforce Financial Service Cloud. But on the step that inserts the financial account records, I get an error stating the following...

FinServ: Too Many Queueable Jobs Added to the Queue: 2

I think this is coming from FSC but I have no idea on the cause as everything is in a managed package, I'm quite literally stuck here. Is there any workaround that I can do?

Comment: You'll probably need to adjust your batch size, perhaps down to 2 or even 1, to avoid exceeding the queueable job limit.

Comment: That could work, but that would take forever no?

Comment: Even so, error still pops up every few batches.